# Is it possible to store an object with functions (proto) as a cookie?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies, web

I have an object called Game, which has properties name, number, teams, etc. Many of its properties are objects themselves: teams is a list of Team objects.
All of these objects have functions defined using proto (not sure of the actual terminology), for example

```
Game.prototype.getName() {
    eturn this.name;
}
```

is one of the game's functions. I want to be able to store the game, along with its functions, as a cookie. I should be able to load this cookie later on and get my original Game object.

JSON.stringify doesn't preserve the functions, just the properties of the Game. Is there anyway I can 'stringify' an entire object including its JavaScript functions? I'm using AngularJS if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should only serialize data, not the behaviour. Once retrieving your data back from JSON you could instanciate relevant Objects with that data, thus giving them back their behaviour.

Comment: Is there a way to automate this?

Comment: Just define constructors for your objects taking JSON parsed data in parameter. These should rebuild your objects structure and data to the same state as before serilization.